# How do I link libraries in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, mingw, libraries

I'm working on a project and it all worked previously in Code::Blocks. A team member is using Eclipse, though, and he has the code from our entire team. He's been working on compiling all of our code in one file. I'm trying to configure Eclipse so that I can show him how to compile my code with third-party libraries. The compiler that I'm using is MinGW. The errors that I'm getting are as follows:

```
01:46:08 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++ ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -static "-LC:\\Users\\Steven\\eclipse-workspace\\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\\thirdparty" -o Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++.exe main.o "-lC:\\Users\\Steven\\eclipse-workspace\\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\\thirdparty\\libboost_filesystem-mgw9-mt-x64-1_73.a" "-lC:\\Users\\Steven\\eclipse-workspace\\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\\thirdparty\\libboost_system-mgw9-mt-x64-1_73.a" "-lC:\\Users\\Steven\\eclipse-workspace\\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\\thirdparty\\libcurl.a" "-lC:\\Users\\Steven\\eclipse-workspace\\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\\thirdparty\\libcurl.dll.a" "-lC:\\Users\\Steven\\eclipse-workspace\\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\\thirdparty\\libxlnt.a" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\Steven\eclipse-workspace\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\thirdparty\libboost_filesystem-mgw9-mt-x64-1_73.a
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\Steven\eclipse-workspace\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\thirdparty\libboost_system-mgw9-mt-x64-1_73.a
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\Steven\eclipse-workspace\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\thirdparty\libcurl.a
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\Steven\eclipse-workspace\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\thirdparty\libcurl.dll.a
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\Steven\eclipse-workspace\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\thirdparty\libxlnt.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

01:46:09 Build Failed. 5 errors, 0 warnings. (took 232ms)
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the reputation to include images, so below are links to screenshots of what I had done to try to include the libraries:

[MinGW C++ Linker Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxUjZ.png)

[MinGW C++ Linker Libraries Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ2CU.png)

Thank you.

Comment: I seem to have linked the libraries by omitting the file path, "lib" at the start of the file name, and the file extension (for example, "curl" and "xlnt"), but now, I have 26 errors all saying "Undefined reference."

Comment: I got it to build! Under `Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Miscellaneous`, I had added `-l` as a linker flag. It didn't create a .exe file, but I'll figure that out on my own.

Comment: It may be nicer to use `-L "C:\\Users\\Steven\\eclipse-workspace\\Ethical-Hacking-with-Computer-Viruses-Using-C++\\thirdparty" -l boost_filesystem-mgw9-mt-x64-1_73` as you then don't have to repeat the path for each library in the same folder.